# Proving the existance and uniqueness of the unit of an adjunction

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, natural-transformations

Let $L: C \to D$ be left adjoint to the functor $R: D \to C.$

For an object $X$ of $C$, we have an isomorphism
$Hom_D(L(X),L(X)) \xrightarrow{\sim} Hom_C(X,(R\circ L)X)$.

Show that there exists a unique morphism of functors $\eta : id_C \to R\circ L$ such that $\eta(X) $is the image of $id_{L(X)}$ under this isomorphism, for every $X\in C$.

Note:$\eta$ is called the unit of the adjunction

My try:

I've tried spelling out the left adjointness in the hypothesis and the morphism of functors of the thesis:

$\forall X \in C$ aand $Y \in D$:
$\alpha_{X,Y}: Hom_D(LX,Y)\cong Hom_C(X,RY)$
s.t
for all $f: X_1 \to X_2$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\operatorname{Hom}_D(LX_2, Y) & \xrightarrow{\alpha_{X_2,Y}} & \operatorname{Hom}_C(X_2, RY) \\
\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle{h \mapsto h\circ L(f)}}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{\scriptstyle{g \mapsto g \circ f}}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
\operatorname{Hom}_D(LX_1, Y)&  \xrightarrow{\alpha_{X_1,Y}} & \operatorname{Hom}_C(X_1, RY)
\end{matrix}
$$

and for all $f: Y_1 \to Y_2$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\operatorname{Hom}_D(LX, Y_1) & \xrightarrow{\alpha_{X,Y_1}} & \operatorname{Hom}_C(X, RY_1) \\
\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle{h \mapsto f\circ h}}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{\scriptstyle{g \mapsto R(f) \circ g}}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
\operatorname{Hom}_D(LX, Y_2)&  \xrightarrow{\alpha_{X,Y_2}} & \operatorname{Hom}_C(X, RY_2)
\end{matrix}
$$

the diagrams commute.

Taking $Y=LX$, I have the diagrams corresponding to the stated isomorphism.   I tried taking

$Y=LX_2$    in the first one   so that I can take $id_{L(X_2)}$ in $Hom_D(LX_2,LX_2) $

and

$Y_1=LX_2, Y_2=LX_1$  in the second one

The thesis should be that $\eta$ is an isomorphism of functors, that is

for each $X \in C$, $\eta_X:\{id_CX \to (R \circ L) X\}_{X \in C}$ s.t

$$
\begin{matrix}
id_C X & \xrightarrow{id_C(f)} & id_C Y  \\
\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle{\eta_X}}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{\scriptstyle{\eta_Y}}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
(R\circ L) X&  \xrightarrow{(R\circ L)f} & (R\circ L) Y
\end{matrix}
$$

commutes.

and  $\eta(X)=\alpha_{X,Y}(id_{L(X)}), X \in C$

**but I am stuck here. I having trouble combining the diagrams above to prove the thesis. How should I do this?**

Moreover I am denoting with  $\eta_X$ the family of morphism that is part of the definition of morphism of functors since that how it was defined in my lecture, as an index of the $\eta$, so I am usure if in this problem $\eta(X)$ is the same denoted differently. Another notational difficulty is that $id_C$ should I be a functor, but the notation makes it look as the identity morphism in the category $C$.

Comment: $\eta$ is not an isomorphism of functors, and yet the diagram that follows is true as it just means that $\eta$ is a _morphism_ of functors. I am not sure how you are getting "stuck" on showing something about $\eta$ if you never even defined it.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев The problem already defines it and I wrote it   in the last line as the image of $id_{L(X)}$ via the isomorphism $\alpha_{X,Y}$

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$I agree it can be confusing to extract properties of $\eta$ from this definition of adjunction ( :) even more so, but doably, in the enriched case). I've done it many times and still always forget how to do it at first glance. In the below I accidentally swapped the roles of $D,C$, please forgive this.

Given $f:X\to Y$, $RL(f)\eta_X$ is what you get if you plug in $1_{LX}$ in the top left corner and follow it around the right hand route in the square: $$\begin{CD}C(LX,LX)@>\cong>>D(X,RLX)\\@VC(1,L(f))VV@VVD(1,R(L(f))V\\C(LX,LY)@>>\cong>D(X,RLY)\end{CD}$$

So $RL(f)\eta_X$ is the transpose of $L(f)$. What's that? Well: $$\begin{CD}C(LY,LY)@>\cong>>D(Y,RLY)\\@VC(Lf,1)VV@VVD(f,1)V\\C(LX,LY)@>>\cong>D(X,RLY)\end{CD}$$If you plug in $1_{LY}
$ in the top left you find that $L(f)$ transpose is just $D(f,1)(\eta_Y)=\eta_Y\circ f$. So $RL(f)\circ\eta_X=\eta_Y\circ f$ as desired!

Notice this "plugging in the identity" business is really about the Yoneda lemma. These natural transformations are equal iff. their values at the identity morphism are equal.

Comment: I take it that in your notation for instance $C(LX, LX)$ is the same as $Hom_C(LX,LX)$. But I don't understand its meaning when you use it in the arrows: what is $C(1,L(f))$ supposed to mean?  If I try to read it analogously $Hom_C(1,L(f))$ makes no sense to me since $1$ and $L(f)$ are not sets

Comment: Is  uniqueness implicit somewhere?

Comment: Are your common diagrams the same as my first two diagrams? Even after exchanging C and D I can't match the second ones, what are you replacing? Also your f goes from X to Y which by definition should be in the same category C or D depending on which diagrams we are talking about yet in the diagrams it seems that X is in C and Y in D

Comment: @some_math_guy Uniqueness is automatic since the adjunction is invertible! There can only be one arrow that transposes to $1_{LX}$. If $C$ is a category it’s also a standard notation to let $C$ denote its hom bifunctor. $C(1,g)$ is the arrow $C(U,V)\to C(U,W)$ given by $h\mapsto g\circ h$, where $g:V\to W$. It’s just what the hom bifunctor does on arrows.

Comment: @darkside Check again? I don’t think there’s any mismatch. In my diagrams $X,Y$ always live in $D$ and$L:D\rightleftarrows C:R$ is how the functors go